# Retriving datas using Json object(webmethod) is not displaying in aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, json, vb.net

I am trying to retrieve data's from SQL server using Json object in Vb.Net.My retrieved values are added to datatable But the added values are not displaying in the aspx page. Why??

My code :

Client-Side :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>View</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID= "lblName" runat="server" Text="Name" ></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text="" /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td> &nbsp </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan ="2" >
           <asp:Button ID="btnShow" Text="Show" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <hr />
    <asp:GridView ID="gvUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2"
    HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2">
    </asp:GridView>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.2/json2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        BindGridView();
    });
    function BindGridView() {
         $("[id*=btnShow]").bind("click", function () {
            var user = {};
            user.Name = $("[id*=txtName]").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "View.aspx/ViewUser",
                data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.t);
                    $("#gvUsers").empty();
                        if (data.d.length > 0) {
                        $("#gvUsers").append("<tr><th>Username</th><th>Password</th></tr>");
                        for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
                            $("#gvUsers").append("<tr><td>" +
                            response.d[i].Username + "</td> <td>" +
                            response.d[i].Password + "</td></tr>");
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
            return;
            });
        };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Code Behind :

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Collections.Generic


Partial Class View
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
      BindDummyItem()
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub BindDummyItem()
    Dim dtGetData As New DataTable()
    dtGetData.Columns.Add("Username")
    dtGetData.Columns.Add("Password")
    dtGetData.Rows.Add()

    gvUsers.DataSource = dtGetData
    gvUsers.DataBind()
End Sub

<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub ViewUser(user As Users)
    Dim Detail As New List(Of Users)()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = @Name")
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", user.Name)
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                sda.Fill(dt)

                For Each dtRow As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    Dim DataObj As New Users()
                    DataObj.Name = dtRow("Username").ToString()
                    DataObj.Password = dtRow("Password").ToString()


                    Detail.Add(DataObj)
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Return
  End Sub
End Class
Public Class Users
  Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _Name = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _Name As String

Public Property Password As String
    Get
        Return _Password
    End Get
    Set(Value As String)
        _Password = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private _Password As String
End Class
```

When I execute this code the retrieved values are added in Detail list but it does not displaying in the web page. Tell me it is the correct procedure to retrieve the data?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**How about this:**

```
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", user.Name)
 cmd.Connection = con
 sda.SelectCommand = cmd
 sda.Fill(dt)


 gvUsers.DataSource = dt
 gvUsers.DataBind()
```

Comment: You are just adding column not a table value.\

Comment: I can't able to add datagrid field in web method.

Comment: Gridview not datagrid

Comment: Yeah i cant able to add Gridview instance in webmethod.